# Is the "too" in the idiom "too clever by half" redundant?

Tags: intensifying-adverbs

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

> Instead, the attempt to be clever by half in his affidavit by having the word "regret" in brackets has only landed him in a soup.

Acoording to [thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/by+half),   "by half" means - An intensifier used to indicate that some quality is excessive or more than is necessary. So it got me into thinking that since "too" has already been used in the idiom, there is no need to use another intensifier (by half). So, I wanted to ask if the "too" in the idiom is redundant?

Comment: Duplicate question.

Comment: Read the second sentence of the definition!

Comment: I deleted my answer as people seem to think the question is a dupe, though I don't see any evidence of that. Why not vote to close if you're so all-fired certain it's a dupe?

Comment: @Robusto- I just wanted to ask if the sentence without "too" would be correct.

Comment: 'Too [adjective] by half' means 'displaying too much of that quality; half as much again as most people would consider normal or necessary'. _By half_ on its own is not an intensifier.